# Using div tags to organize my layout instead of tables

Tags: html

I would like to organize the layout of a report (see link to image below) to use div elements instead of tables. How can I do that? I have the report converted into tables but I am not sure how to achieve the same look using div tags.
I have converted the report to html but it uses a table layout. I am not familiar with how to do the same using div tags. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is fiddle for the HTML/Table layout:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/xrbYXZ

Here is a link to the image of the report
[layout of report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyoIh.png)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this with  tags you can use CSS classes.  Apply a class for "Table", "tRow", "tHead", "tCell".  This is an example I found here: [HTML-Cleaner.com](https://html-cleaner.com/features/replace-html-table-tags-with-divs/)

```
<html>
    <h2>Phone numbers</h2>
    <div class="rTable">
    <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Name</strong></div>
    <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Telephone</span></div>
    <div class="rTableHead">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell">John</div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><a href="tel:0123456785">0123 456 785</a></div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rTableRow">
    <div class="rTableCell">Cassie</div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><a href="tel:9876532432">9876 532 432</a></div>
    <div class="rTableCell"><img src="images/check.gif" alt="checked" /></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

For CSS style, at minimum:

```
.rTable { display: table; }
.rTableRow { display: table-row; }
.rTableHeading { display: table-header-group; }
.rTableBody { display: table-row-group; }
.rTableFoot { display: table-footer-group; }
.rTableCell, .rTableHead { display: table-cell; }
```

Additional CSS styling (for color and borders, etc.) - example:

```
    .rTable {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .rTableRow {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableCell, .rTableHead {
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 3px 10px;
        border: 1px solid #999999;
    }
    .rTableHeading {
        display: table-header-group;
        background-color: #ddd;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    .rTableFoot {
        display: table-footer-group;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #ddd;
    }
    .rTableBody {
        display: table-row-group;
    }
```

The same source has an HTML table "converter" worth trying.

Comment: Thanks for the info but my biggest issue is how to layout the look of the report in the linked image using the div tags. Once I have the layout I can use the above information to convert from tables to divs.